# Convert list to namedtuple

Tags: python

In python 3, I have a tuple `Row` and a list `A`:

```
Row = namedtuple('Row', ['first', 'second', 'third'])
A = ['1', '2', '3']
```

How do I initialize `Row` using the list `A`? Note that in my situation I cannot directly do this:

```
newRow = Row('1', '2', '3')
```

I have tried different methods

```
1. newRow = Row(Row(x) for x in A)
2. newRow = Row() + data             # don't know if it is correct
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can do `Row(*A)` which uses argument unpacking.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Row = namedtuple('Row', ['first', 'second', 'third'])
>>> A = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> Row(*A)
Row(first='1', second='2', third='3')
```

Note that if your linter doesn't complain too much about using methods which start with an underscore, `namedtuple` provides a [`_make`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make) classmethod alternate constructor.

```
>>> Row._make([1, 2, 3])
```

Don't let the underscore prefix fool you -- this *is* part of the documented API for this class and can be relied upon to be there in all python implementations, etc...

Comment: a little cheesy - but I just learned something that you knew 10 YEARS AGO. A big thank you to PAST you as well as to current you for helping others along the way!

Answer (score 1):

The namedtuple Subclass has a method named '_make'.
Inserting an Array (Python List) into a namedtuple Objects it's easy using the method '_make':

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Row = namedtuple('Row', ['first', 'second', 'third'])
>>> A = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> Row._make(A)
Row(first='1', second='2', third='3')

>>> c = Row._make(A)
>>> c.first
'1'
```